A possible application of deformation theory?
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued polynomial function.  Consider the family of real algebraic sets:
$$
V_c = f^{-1}(c), \quad c \in (-1,1).
$$
I am interested in determining how the connected components of $V_c$ change as $c$ varies. I might have some partial information in the case $c = 0$.
Consider the morphism of schemes:
$$
\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R[ x_1, \cdots, x_d, c] / (f -c) \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R
$$
Note: I want to restrict the parameter, $c$, to be between only $-1$ and $1$. However, I am not sure how to make sense of it since $(-1,1)$ is not an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R$ with the Zariski topology. Moreover, the morphism must satisfy some special properties, I believe, but let's ignore that detail for now.
Naively, I am thinking of this problem through the lens of deformation theory. We would like to deform the set $V_0$ infinitesimally and observe how its topological properties change. Then, we'd like to argue that the change in topological properties remains stable as long as $c$ has the same parity and is less than one. My initial numerical investigations seem to suggest this is true.
Can we use techniques in deformation theory to tackle this problem?
Naively, I would expect to compute $H^0$ associated to the morphism above and see how the rank of $H^0$ depends on $c$. However, I don't know enough technical details to say if this is the right approach.
Note: My problem has some special structure. Write the coordinates of $ \mathbb R^{n_1 + \cdots + n_d}$ as $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_d)$. The polynomial $f : \mathbb{R}^{n_1 + \cdots + n_d} \to \mathbb{R}$ is of the form:
$$
f(x_1, \cdots,x_d) = \prod_{k=1}^d f_k(x_k)
$$
Here each $f_k$ is a real-valued polynomial
